# How to stop video from playing on scroll?

Tags: javascript, html, video, viewport

I am using for viewport to play/pause the video. However, once the video ends and I scroll, it restarts. Any way to make it end and stop playing once its done?

I am using the following viewport code to control its function:

```
(function($) {

  $(document).ready(function() { 
  
    var $win = $(window);
    
    var elementTop, elementBottom, viewportTop, viewportBottom;

    function isScrolledIntoView(elem) {
      elementTop = $(elem).offset().top;
      elementBottom = elementTop + $(elem).outerHeight();
      viewportTop = $win.scrollTop();
      viewportBottom = viewportTop + $win.height();
      return (elementBottom > viewportTop && elementTop < viewportBottom);
    }
        
    if($('video').length){

      var loadVideo;

      $('video').each(function(){
        $(this).attr('webkit-playsinline', '');
        $(this).attr('playsinline', '');

        $(this).attr('id','loadvideo');
        loadVideo = document.getElementById('loadvideo');
        loadVideo.load();
      });

      $win.scroll(function () { // video to play when is on viewport 
      
        $('video').each(function(){
          if (isScrolledIntoView(this) == true) {
              $(this)[0].play();
          } else {
              $(this)[0].pause();
          }
        });
      
      });  // video to play when is on viewport

    } // end .field--name-field-video
    
    
   });
  
})(jQuery);
```